# ReflectionUtils.setFieldIfPossible method not found while running tests with Micronaut framework

Tags: java, frameworks, micronaut

I am trying to launch a basic test with Micronaut, it's the one that came with the generated project. The test fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.micronaut.core.reflect.ReflectionUtils.setFieldIfPossible(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'

    at io.micronaut.configuration.archaius1.EnvironmentDeploymentContext.close(EnvironmentDeploymentContext.java:210)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.archaius1.$EnvironmentDeploymentContextDefinition.dispose(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.inject.DisposableBeanDefinition.dispose(DisposableBeanDefinition.java:44)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.destroyBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1148)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.destroyBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1119)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.stop(DefaultBeanContext.java:406)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.stop(DefaultApplicationContext.java:200)
    at io.micronaut.servlet.engine.server.AbstractServletServer.stop(AbstractServletServer.java:105)
    at io.micronaut.servlet.engine.server.AbstractServletServer.stop(AbstractServletServer.java:34)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.stopEmbeddedApplication(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:483)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.afterClass(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:397)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.afterAll(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:209)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$18(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$19(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:461)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:235)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:161)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:161)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

This is the test that I'm trying to launch, nothing fancy in there:

```
@Inject
    EmbeddedApplication<?> application;

    @Test
    void testItWorks() {
        Assertions.assertTrue(application.isRunning());
    }
```

From what I saw, the ReflectionUtils is not having that method it calls anymore starting with version 3.x, only setFields is exposed now.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit, added pom.xml file content:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-management</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-session</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.kubernetes</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-kubernetes-client</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.kubernetes</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-kubernetes-informer</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.netflix</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-serde-jackson</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-spring-boot</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-spring-web</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-mongo-sync</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <configFile>aot-${packaging}.properties</configFile>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.self="override">
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-data-document-processor</artifactId>
              <version>3.9.6</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.openapi</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-openapi</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.openapi.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-serde-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-spring-annotation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.spring.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-spring-boot-annotation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.spring.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-spring-web-annotation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.spring.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=fr.tas.co2m</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=tradeoff</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <to>
            <image>${jib.docker.image}:${jib.docker.tag}</image>
          </to>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Please provide more context. How did you generate the app? What JDK version your running on? How does your `build.gradle` look like?

Comment: With which version of Micronaut are you able to produce that error?

Comment: I used the launch page (https://micronaut.io/launch), Micronaut version 3.8.5 with JDK 17.  I added the dependencies with the launcher, could some of them still be in conflict with each other? I added the pom.xml in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it was indeed a dependency that was causing this, removing micronaut-netflix-hystrix fixed it.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.netflix</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```